# How do I determine progress when reading a file

Tags: java, file, javafx, task

I'm using JavaFX `Task` to read a text file and parse it into a `HashMap<String, String>` (using a`Mapper<String, String` object). My code is fully functioning, but I wish to show read progress to user as the input file contains over 9000 rows of data.

```
@Override
protected Mapper<String, String> call() throws Exception {
    // Read and parse contents of source mapping file.

    /* Format:
     * Ignore first line of file, then:
     * 
     * <old_name>       <new_name>
     *  NAME_A              NAME_X              
     *  NAME_B              NAME_Y               
     *  NAME_C              NAME_Z
     *
     * Where <old_name> = K, <new_name> = V in Mapper object.
     */

    int i=beginReadingFileFromLine; // Ignore first line of file
    String line;
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    updateMessage("Loading data...");
    while ( (line=FileUtils.readLine(sourceMappingFilePath, i)) != null ) {
        // Parse line into String[] split by delim char.
        String[] parsedLine = line.split(fileDelimChar);
        keys.add(parsedLine[0]);
        values.add(parsedLine[1]);
        i++;
    }
    updateProgress(i, i);
    updateMessage("Data loaded!");
    return new Mapper<String, String>(keys, values);
}
```

In the existing state of this code, I can't think of a way to determine how much of the input file I've read. The method `FileUtils.readLine(sourceMappingFilePath, i)` above is a custom implementation:

```
 /**
 * Reads a single line, according to supplied line number from specified file.
 * @param filepath
 * @param lineNumber zero based index.
 * @return  Line from file without linefeed character. NULL if at EoF.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static String readLine(String filepath, int lineNumber) throws IOException {
    FileReader fReader = new FileReader(filepath);
    LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(fReader);

    String desiredLine = null; 

    int i=0;
    String line;
    while( (line=lineNumberReader.readLine()) != null) {

        if(lineNumber==i) {
            desiredLine=line;
        }
        i++;
    }
    lineNumberReader.close();
    return desiredLine;
}
```

Any suggestions? The simpler to implement, the better - thanks for your time.

Comment: JavaDoc for your reference: [Task<V>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

Comment: I think `bytes read` / `total bytes` would be the real progress

Comment: Your utility method is very inefficient (this is putting it mildly). To read each line, you open the file from scratch, and scan through the file to the last line read, and then get the next line. So to read 9000 lines, in total you read through 1+2+3+...+9000=40,504,500 lines, opening and closing the file 9000 times. Perhaps if you just read the file, you won't even really need a progress indicator (or could just use an indeterminate one).

Comment: @James_D Thanks for this, I was being lazy and used this utility function which I had written for another project to save time. I'll look into NIO channel/buffer, apparently it's quite fast.

Comment: For just 9000 lines I would think a regular buffered reader would perform just fine.

Comment: @James_D My test file is 9000 rows, but user may feed in a significantly larger file. Besides, I don't think I can determine bytes read from a `BufferedReader` as @Daniel Puiu has suggested.

Comment: Sure you can. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is to use an underlying input stream that tracks how many bytes you have read. The `Files.size()` method will give you the total number of bytes in a file, so this gives you enough information to compute the overall progress. You can do something like

```
public class CountingInputStream extends InputStream implements AutoCloseable {

    private long bytesRead = 0 ;

    private final InputStream stream ;

    public CountingInputStream(InputStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream ;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int result = stream.read() ;
        if (result != -1) {
            bytesRead++;
        }
        return result ;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        stream.close();
    }

    public long getBytesRead() {
        return bytesRead ;
    }
}
```

Note that if you wrap this in a `BufferedReader`, `getBytesRead()` will return the number of bytes read from the underlying stream, including those still stored in the buffer. This is probably good enough for displaying a progress bar (since it's very fast to read from the buffer), but isn't going to be technically 100% accurate.

Here's a SSCCE. On my system, you need to load a file with ~100,000 lines to see the progress bar. You can create one if you don't have one available (the SSCCE allows you to create a file first).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ReadFileWithProgress extends Application {


    public static class CountingInputStream extends InputStream implements AutoCloseable {

        private long bytesRead = 0 ;

        private final InputStream stream ;

        public CountingInputStream(InputStream stream) {
            this.stream = stream ;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            int result = stream.read() ;
            if (result != -1) {
                bytesRead++;
            }
            return result ;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            stream.close();
        }

        public long getBytesRead() {
            return bytesRead ;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        TextField numLinesField = new TextField();

        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();

        Button create = new Button("Create File...");
        create.setOnAction(e -> {
            int numLines = Integer.parseInt(numLinesField.getText());
            File file = chooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    createFile(file.toPath(), numLines);
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Button loadFile = new Button("Load file");
        ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(0);
        loadFile.setOnAction(e -> {
            File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            if (file != null) {
                Task<Map<String, String>> task = readFileTask(file.toPath());
                progress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
                task.setOnSucceeded(evt -> new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "File loaded", ButtonType.OK).showAndWait());
                task.setOnFailed(evt -> new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "File could not be loaded", ButtonType.OK).showAndWait());
                new Thread(task).start();
            }
        });

        root.addRow(0, new Label("Number of lines:"), numLinesField, create);
        root.add(loadFile, 0, 1, 3, 1);
        root.add(progress, 0, 2, 3, 1);

        GridPane.setFillWidth(progress, true);
        GridPane.setHalignment(progress, HPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setFillWidth(loadFile, true);
        GridPane.setHalignment(loadFile, HPos.CENTER);

        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.setHgap(5);
        root.setVgap(10);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Task<Map<String, String>> readFileTask(Path path) {

        return new Task<Map<String, String>>() {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> call() throws IOException {
                try (
                        CountingInputStream input = new CountingInputStream(Files.newInputStream(path));
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    ) {

                        long totalBytes = Files.size(path);

                        return in.lines()
                                .peek(line -> updateProgress(input.getBytesRead(), totalBytes))
                                .map(line -> line.split("\t"))
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(tokens -> tokens[0], tokens -> tokens[1]));
                    }

            }

        };

    }

    private void createFile(Path path, int numEntries) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numEntries ; i++) {
                out.write(String.format("key %d\tvalue %d%n", i, i));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a good SSCCE. You really didn't have to be this thorough, but I immensely appreciate such a precise but concise response. Jolly good work sir!

Comment: @orion_IX I wasn't sure it would work without testing it ;).

Comment: hallmark of a great coder! ;) on another note, good folks like you make SO such a worthwhile experience, as opposed to fumbling around and giving up in the end!